Is it possible to build a foundation and walls that insects cannot chew through (ants, termites)?
Is it possible to build a structure such that insects (eg ants) cannot burrow holes though the foundation and exterior walls?
I had always assumed that you could keep mice, roaches, ants, flys, etc out of a kitchen if that kitchen was well-sealed. For example: concrete foundation, masonry walls, weather stripping doors, and fly-screened windows.
But I recently learned that ants can chew through concrete. So they can literally enter through a concrete foundation or masonry walls (either directly through the concrete blocks or mortar.
Besides using toxic chemicals, is there any physical barrier that can be used in construction to keep insects out of a structure?

Everything will break eventually. So how long timeframe are we talking here.

Ants will not eat through poured concrete.  Ants will take advantage of cracks.  I suggest that completely sealing a kitchen is not a useful endeavor, especially since you generally want electricity and water there.

Insect-proofing a building is a common headache in every tropical environment around the world. The practical solution is a poured slab floor and concrete/cinder block construction. When they chew through, set out poison traps.

It is impossible to vermin proof a house. There is always a gap underneath every door and depending on the size of gap, various insects can enter a house by crawling through the gap underneath external doors.
Also, depending on the style of roof, insects can crawl on the outside walls, onto the roof, get into the roof space and then into the rest of the house from there. Additionally, they can gain access via gaps in windows.

I think it's possible to build doors that do not have gaps. Refrigerator doors do not have gaps. Same with windows.
